# independent units in a proof of Dirichlet's unit theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a integer ring of number field $K$ with degree $n$. $\sigma_1\dots \sigma_{r_1}$ are real embedding of $K$, $\sigma_{r_1+1}\dots \sigma_{r_1+2r_2}$ are complex embedding of $K$ (where $\sigma_{r_1+j}, \sigma_{r_1+r_2+j}$ are complex conjugate). We set $r=r_1+r_2-1$.

**Lemma1.**
$M=(m_{ij})\in M_t(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies $m_{ii}>0,m_{ij}<0(i\neq j),\sum_j m_{ij}>0$. Then $M$ is regular.

**Lemma2.**
If $r>0$, there exist units $\epsilon_1\dots \epsilon_{r+1}$ such that $|\sigma_i(\epsilon_i)|>1$, $|\sigma_j(\epsilon_i)|<1(j\neq i)$ (for any $i$).

Then in a proof of Dirichlet's unit theorem (in a book I have),what we next to show is that **any** $r$ elements of $\{\ell(\epsilon_i)\}_{i=1\dots r+1}$ are linearly independent where we defined $\ell\colon {\mathcal{O}_K}^{\times}\to \mathbb{R}^{r+1}$ as 
$$
\ell (\epsilon)=(\log |\sigma_1(\epsilon)|,\dots,\log |\sigma_{r_1}(\epsilon)|,2\log |\sigma_{r_1+1}(\epsilon)|,\dots,2\log |\sigma_{r_1+r_2}(\epsilon)|)
$$

I understand $\{\ell(\epsilon_i)\}_{i=1\dots r}$ are linearly independent, and this is enough to show this theorem. But I'm not sure the "any" is also right.

Comment: What do you get when you add all the vectors $\ell(e)$?

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer What is $e$?

Comment: $e$ is $\epsilon$

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Well, is it always well-defined (i.e. finite sum) ? I don't figure out what you intend.

Comment: I was confused, sorry. But why does the proof that the first $r$ units are independent not work for an arbitrary selection? All you have to do is permute the embeddings.

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer You are right, thank you. I would be grateful if you would answer to my other questions.