# Herbrand's unit theorem

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $L / K$ be Galois extension of number fields with degree $n$, $U_{K},U_{L}$ be an unit group of an integer ring $\mathcal{O}_K,\mathcal{O}_L$ of $K,L$.

$\sigma_1\dots \sigma_{r_K}$ are real embedding of $K$, $\sigma_{r_K+1}\dots \sigma_{r_K+2s_K}$ are complex embedding of $K$ (where $\sigma_{r_K+j}, \sigma_{r_K+s_K+j}$ are complex conjugate). We set $r\colon=r_K+s_K-1$.

Book now I'm reading says Artin proved following theorem by improving Herbrand's theorem.

> There exist $r+1$ units $\eta_1\dots\eta_{r+1}\in U_L$ such that
>
> (a) For all $i=1\dots r+1$, $N_{L/K}\eta_i=1$ or already $N_{F/K}\eta_i=1$ ($F$ is real subfield of $L$)
>
> (b) $U'\colon=\left\langle \{\sigma_i(\eta_j)\}_{i=1\dots n,\ 
>  j=1\dots r+1}\cup U_K \right\rangle$ is finite index subroup
>    of $U_L$

But this is not valid statement I think. It seems to $[L:F]=1,2$, but I'm bit confused existence of $F$, when $\eta_i$ belongs to $F$ and so on. So I want ask you to strictly state this in details and prove this.

Comment: @reuns I made a mistake and you are right. I edited thank you. ($\mathcal{O}_K^{\times}=U_K,\mathcal{O}_L^{\times}=U_L$)

Comment: Could you copy the complete statement of the theorem? I don't understand the role of $F$.

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer Well, what I did is mostly only changing some symbols (The book (wrote by Takagi) is originally very tedious and not very formal or accurate and I don't understand the book very well).

As for $F$, the book states before this theorem. Like,

Comment: "Let $L_i,K_i$ be conjugate fields of $L,K$ (i=1\dots r_K+s_K). Consider the case $L_i$ are real for $i=1\dots r_K'$ and complex for $i=r_K'+1\dots r_K$. At this time, let $\bar{\sigma}$ is quadratic autmorphism of $L_i/K_i$ such that it send for each element to complex conjugate. Then $F$ is subfield of degree $n/2$ corresponding to $1, \bar{\sigma}$.".

Comment: I am also confused. Is Takagi's book written in Japanese? As for the "improvement": Does Takagi need the stronger version anywhere?

Comment: @franz lemmermeyer Yes, in Japanese. This theorem is needed to compute Herbrand quotient of unit group.

Comment: Incidentally, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3504705/a-certain-finite-index-subgroup-of-an-unit-group-of-a-number-field is needed for same purpose. So I want to understand any of these, for now.